# credit card payment with paypal sandbox returns response as "state": "created"?

Tags: android, paypal

I have integrated Paypal in my android application, user can pay by credit card or paypal account.While doing paypal account payment working fine, am getting response as "status" : "approved" then merchant account credited successfully..

while doing Card Payment, am getting response as "status": "created" instead of "approved". and merchant account not credit the specified amount?

Environment : sandbox.

Response while doing the card payment:

```
"response": {
    "state": "created",
    "id": "PAY-92898807R9269472DK6NSSTA",
    "create_time": "2016-07-29T10:00:44Z",
    "intent": "sale"
    },
    "client": {
    "platform": "Android",
    "paypal_sdk_version": "2.14.4",
    "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK",
    "environment": "sandbox"
    },
    "response_type": "payment"
    }
```

Is there any mistake in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the "state": "approved" and merchant account credit with specified amount in sandbox environment for credit card payment. The problem is I created the Business account in my sandbox, but we need to create Business-Pro account in sandbox..

Comment: but i have one more doubt, Is the transaction fully completed?